# Go Project not recognizing one import but all others work fine

Tags: go

The projects runs and I see not errors. However, I am trying to use `"github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"` but the import is always removed.

I have done the following.

```
go get "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
```

I now see it but it is greyed out compared to the others

```
go 1.20

require (
    github.com/alexedwards/flow v0.0.0-20220806114457-cf11be9e0e03
    github.com/fatih/color v1.15.0
    golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20230321023759-10a507213a29
)

require (
    github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig v1.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.13 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.17 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.6.0 // indirect
)
```

Ran `go mod download`

Try to add the import back to where I need it

```
package config

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"  <-- gets removed
)

type OAuth struct {
    Key          string    `envconfig:"APP_KEY" default:""`
    Secret       string    `envconfig:"APP_SECRET" default:""`
```

same thing happens, so I run `go mod tidy` and now my import is gone in my `go.mod` file.

I refresh and re-index my project, do the same process again with the same result. I deleted the `go.mod` file, reinitialized with no avail.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi @Mike3355. You are most likely not using that import in your code currently, which is why it is marked as an `indirect` import in go.mod and why it is removed when running `tidy`, which automatically removes unused imports. If not, please show a snippet of your code that uses it. Have a good day

Comment: @Ullaakut I did post it. It is the struct and the import is not there because it get removed

Comment: Struct tags don't need an import (they're just strings). There must be some code that uses the struct tags, and that code should have the envconfig import.

Answer (score 0):

You are only using `envconfig` as a tag for marshal/unmarshal. So it will be removed as it's not used. You need to **USE** `envconfig` in your codes.
For example

```
type Foo struct{
     Bar string `envconfig:"bar"`
}
var data []byte // some marshalled data
var foo Foo
envconfig.Unmarshall(&foo,data) // not sure if this is the correct syntax, but you should get the idea
```

and now since `envconfig` is being used, it will no longer be removed from your imports.